# grant and delete permissions on a network shared folder in Powershell preferably without alias

Tags: powershell

What's a good way of deleting permissions on a shared folder which I shared by using :

`NET SHARE MyFolder=C:\FolderX\Subfolder1 "/GRANT:Everyone,Full"` (this makes \MyServer\MyFolder\Subfolder1 accessible from Explorer by Everyone!)

I am interested in having this permission removed e.g. \MyServer\MyFolder\Subfolder1 will no longer be available to Everyone (but the folder will physically remain)

Also, what's a good way of modifying the current access of a folder? e.g. running this twice won't work: `NET SHARE MyFolder=C:\FolderX\Subfolder1 "/GRANT:Everyone,Full"`
because MyFolder already exists!

Is it possible to grant permission without creating an artificial share name? so that \MyServer\FolderX\Subfolder1, instead of \MyServer\Subfolder1, is available. Surely it's possible, because, manually it can be done. When you give the access manually in windows you needn't create an artificial share name (alias).
Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. First you say you want to remove share permissions, but then you say you want to modify permissions without creating a share. Share permissions can only be set on a shared folder, however NTFS permissions (Security-tab) can be set without a share. Is that what you're talking about? Share perm. and NTFS perm. are very different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove NTFS-permissions from a user (which gives access to a resource locally/interactive on the computer), use `Get-ACL` and `Set-ACL`.

```
#Get ACL-object (NTFS-security)
$acl = Get-Acl -Path .\Test

#Get access rules for EVERYONE
$everyone = $acl.Access | Where-Object { $_.IdentityReference -match 'Everyone' }

#Remove all access rules for EVERYONE
$modified = @($everyone | Foreach-Object { $acl.RemoveAccessRule($_) }) -contains $true

if($modified) {
    #AccessRules modified, save.
    Set-Acl -Path .\Test -AclObject $acl
}
```

Comment: Thank you Frode, this is what I needed!